# How to load the PowerShell script that was in different directory while executing test case

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am having my `.ps1` saved in `directory1` and mt `.tests.ps1` in `directory2` with in the same folder

[image]

In general we use to write the script as follows when the test file and script file are in the same folder

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$sut = (Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -replace '\.Tests\.', '.'
. "$here\$sut"
```

But I am having them in different folder, so how can I load the path so that the script file should get loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have coded as follows which works fine

```
$project = (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).Replace(".Tests", "")
$sut = (Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).Replace(".tests.", ".")
. "$project\$sut"
```